# Function that accepts any pointer type

Tags: c++

I have a function `void Foo(MyType* mt)`. I want callers to be able to pass any pointer type to this function (e.g. `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr` or `iterator`) and not require passing a raw pointer. Is there any way to express this? I could write:

```
template <typename T>
void Foo(T t);
```

This will work since it will only compile if `T` supports `operator->` and `operator*` which I use inside `Foo`, it will also only work if `T` has the same interface as `MyType` but it seems wrong to not specify in the API that I expect that template argument to be a pointer to `MyType`. I could also write my own wrapper:

```
template <typename T>
class PointerWrapper {
 public:
  PointerWrapper(T* t) : raw_ptr(t) {}
  PointerWrapper(const std::unique_ptr<T>& t) : raw_ptr(t.get()) {}
  ...
 private:
  T* raw_ptr;
};

void Foo(PointerWrapper<MyType> mt);
```

This seems clunky because I will need to extend PointerWrapper for every smart pointer type under the sun.

Is there an accepted way to support this?

Comment: Your original solution matches the way standard algorithms work, so people who pass the wrong types just get hideous errors.  You can probably use concepts (introduced in C++20) to make your requirements more clear, but I haven't used them enough to give you a starting point.

Comment: Here's an idea: ditch that idea and accept a reference instead. Let the caller worry about ownership and abstraction and "smartness". (Possibly controversial opinion: if you're thinking of `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr`, and iterators as pointers, you're on the wrong track.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C++20, you'd write a concept such as

```
template <typename P, typename T>
concept points_to = requires(P p) {
    { *p } -> std::common_reference_with<T &>
} && std::equality_comparable_with<std::nullptr_t>

template <points_to<MyType> T>
void Foo(T t);
```

Prior to that, you could write something involving `std::pointer_traits`

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<MyType, typename std::pointer_traits<T>::element_type>> Foo(T t);
```

Answer (score 3):

> I want callers to be able to pass any pointer type to this function (e.g. unique_ptr, shared_ptr or iterator

Don't.

Each kind of smart (or dumb) pointer has a very specific purpose, illustrated below.

```
void foo(std::shared_ptr<T>);  // I will assume joint ownership 
                               // that may or may not outlive the call

void foo(std::unique_ptr<T>);  // I will take your ownership away
                               // You better not be needing it anymore

void foo(T*);                  // I am just borrowing it
                               // Whoever owns it should not worry
```

It makes little sense for a function to either take ownership or not, depending on what kind of pointer the user passes.

And, naturally, if your function does not do any iterating things, it should not take iterators.